# Form placeholder taking php code only once

Tags: php

When first time user upload non jpeg/gif file or bigger than 2mb Form Placeholder takes php value correctly but second times form is blank and user needs to retype. What is the problem in following code :

```
<form method="post" id="comment" name="comment" action=""enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <textarea id="readerInput" name="readerInput" maxlength='950' placeholder="<?php echo $message ?>"></textarea>
  </form>



<?php
      $message = 'Your Comment';
      $name = 'Your Name';
      $email = 'Your eMail';

      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $name = $_POST['name'];
        $message = $_POST['readerInput'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

      if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
            $tmp_image = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                    $file = $finfo->file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); 

      if($file!=='image/jpeg' && $file !=='image/gif' || $tmp_image > 1024*1024*2)
      { 
        echo '<script> alert("Your Image should be in jpg/gif format ?")</script>';             

                    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You have `echo $message` before you assign `$message = `$_POST['readerInput']`.

Comment: In actual file order is right. PHP code is written before form and it is working fine but only for the first time.

Comment: Please show the actual script. How can we know what you did wrong if you post something different?